# Upgraded and digikam ignores most folders

Tags: digikam

I have a new laptop and I've copied across my photo collection and digikam set up.  But when I open up digikam, it shows me very few of my albums.  I faithfully copied across my settings, including:

- `~/.kde/share/apps/digikam/*`
- `~/.kde/share/config/digikamrc`
- `~/Photos/*` with all my photos and including the sqlite database `digikam4.db`

But when I started, digikam didn't find most of my albums.  I opened up digikam4.db from backups and after digikam had opened, and found that most of my albums had been deleted.  How can I get digikam to show everything again?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that digikam saves the **full path** to the photos directory, not just relative to your home directory.  I had to correct this in a few places as I had changed username when moving laptops, so the full path to the photos had changed from `/home/user1/Photos` to `/home/user2/Photos`.

First I had to edit the text file digikamrc - `gedit ~/.kde/share/config/digikamrc` and search for `user1`.  The settings were called "Database Name" and "Database Name Thumbnails".

Then I had to edit some settings in the sqlite file.  I did this by using the sqlitebrowser GUI app which allowed me to open digikam4.db, choose each table one by one, and then edit the contents by double-clicking on a cell in a table.  The tables that needed updating were:

- **AlbumRoots** - this had the full path to the albums in the `identifier` column.  I had to change `volumeid:?path=%2Fhome%2Fuser1%2FPhotos` to `volumeid:?path=%2Fhome%2Fuser2%2FPhotos` and similar
- **Tags** - the `iconkde` column has some entries where the tag image is a photo, which is saved as the full path to the photo, so they needed their paths updating.